# Does .NET 8 support web jobs? or they are converted in to a function?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-webjobs, .net-8.0, azure-webjobssdk

Azure Functions v 4 has recently been announed, but are web jobs still there with .NET 8?
Or do we need to consider Azure Functions as web job and schedule it?

I'm referring to these links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net8%2Cazure-cli%2Cwindows&pivots=programming-language-csharp

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Perhaps you need to ask the *reverse*? Do Web Jobs, a specific Azure Service,  support .NET 8? The NuGet package targets .NET Standard so works in all supported .NET Core and Framework versions. You won't be able to run your application if *Azure Web Jobs* doesn't use .NET 8 though

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As @*Panagiotis Kanavos* mentioned `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core` package supports **.NET 8.0**.

- Azure WebJobs are a feature of Azure App Service, which is a platform for hosting web applications such as Azure Functions and Azure WebJobs.
- The same can find in the [NuGet Gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core) as shown below:

[image]